# No sound from VirtualBox after resuming saved system state

Tags: sound, virtualbox, resume

I save guest's state, then suspend laptop, then turn in on, load guest's state and there is no sound from VritualBox. Though there is sound from the host.
So I have to restart the guest.

VBox 6.1.10, Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Comment: you could probably just restart the audio instead of the entire guest.... pulseaudio -k or pkill pulseaudio... I also lose audio frequently... sometimes it even comes back on it's own. i think i've set it to automatically respawn, but I dont know if that works consistently

Comment: @WU-TANG this time guest reboot didn't help and killing pulseaudio didn't help either.

Comment: Yeah, it's been a mystery to me too. I don't know think it's a ubuntu problem, especially since I rarely ever see it happen on the host. i am actually experiencing it as I am typing this. 3 ubuntu VMs up: 1-MATE 20.04 no sound, 1 GNOME and 1 MATE, 20.04 with sound. And the host has sound. Even my Centos 7 VM that I use has the same issue... I've accidentally hit the shutdown on the host plenty of times which automatically saves the guests, so I've probably had your issue too... but being that the audio automatically fixes itself at some point, ive probably never noticed. There are log messages

Comment: Same here. Virtualbox 6.1.36 on Windows 11 Host with Mint 20.3 guest. After the guest goes to sleep and I login again, the sound fails. Restarting the vbox guest fixes it.